# How to establish an equation from given data for y prediction?

Tags: python

I have x-y data how to establish function from these data for prediction of y using x values in python?

```
X             Y
396.470001 => 0.012
401.480011 => 0.020
406.48999  => 0.026
411.5      => 0.032
416.51001  => 0.037
777.130005 => 0.357
782.140015 => 0.361
787.150024 => 0.363
792.159973 => 0.365
797.169983 => 0.366
817.200012 => 0.370
832.22998  => 0.373
897.340027 => 0.383
902.349976  =>0.384
907.359985  =>0.384
1092.680054 =>0.388
1097.689941 =>0.387
1102.699951 =>0.385
1283.01001  =>0.299
1293.030029 =>0.294
1298.040039 =>0.291
1303.040039 =>0.287
1308.050049 =>0.282
1313.060059 =>0.277
1318.069946 =>0.270
1323.079956 =>0.263
1328.089966 =>0.254
1333.099976 =>0.244
1338.099976 =>0.233
1343.109985 =>0.221
1348.119995 =>0.207
1443.290039 =>0.095
1628.609985 =>0.149
1633.619995 =>0.151
1638.619995 =>0.152
1643.630005 =>0.153
1648.640015 =>0.154
1653.650024 =>0.154
1658.660034 =>0.155
1663.670044 =>0.155
1668.680054 =>0.155
1673.689941 =>0.155
1678.689941 =>0.154
1683.699951 =>0.154
1688.709961 =>0.153
1693.719971 =>0.152
1698.72998  =>0.151
1703.73999  =>0.150
1708.75     =>0.148
1713.75     =>0.146
1718.76001  =>0.145
1723.77002  =>0.143
1728.780029 =>0.141
1733.790039 =>0.139
1738.800049 =>0.137
1743.810059 =>0.135
1748.819946 =>0.132
1753.819946 =>0.130
1758.829956 =>0.127
1763.839966 =>0.125
1768.849976 =>0.122
1959.180054 =>0.053
2500.120117 =>0.097
```

The curve looks like this:

[image: graph]

I tried all polynomial degree but it doesn't fit well.

Comment: "all polynomial degree" can you elaborate on that? Show some of the code you tried.

Comment: This is really a question about statistical modeling rather than programming. The data are oddly grouped, with many close (and redundant) measurements and big gaps.  Are the single point dips at 1443 and 1959 real or outlier artifacts?  More data are needed.  Polynomials are definitely wrong.  Perhaps a log-normal or other non-linear curve that rises from 0,0 and tapers off would work.

Comment: In agreement with @TerryJanReedy, I would suggest that you ask for advice on, for instance, http://stats.stackexchange.com/. Especially if you want to use your model for prediction purposes a (simple) polynomial fit would be ill-advised. As one of my old professors put it forty years ago, a snake is flexible enough to fit any data but you can't know where its head or tail will go. I would also ask whether you have any *a priori* knowledge about the process that gave rise to these data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this online sites to get the polynomial equation between X and Y.

[http://www.xuru.org/rt/PR.asp](http://www.xuru.org/rt/PR.asp#CopyPaste)